# How to find the differential equation given an exponential solution?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this equation: $A(t)=(a)(1-e^{bt} )+ct$

where $a$, $b$, $c$ are constants.

I'm getting the first derivative as: $A'(t)= -ab(e^{bt})+c$   (call this equation 1).

I can also write $e^{bt} = 1-\frac{A-ct}{a}$

So, the first derivative becomes: $A'(t)=-ab(1-(A-ct)/a)+c$  (call this equation 2)

Simplifying gives: $A'(t)= bA - cbt + c-ab$

Is this correct? I'm not getting the same answer from equations 1 and 2 for $A'(t)$. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your calculations are correct.

If you substitute $A(t)=a(1-e^{bt})+ct$ into the simplified version of (2), which is $A'(t)=bA(t)-cbt+c-ab$, you will recover (1).